# ICC Calibration (Profile) for more bright black on LED screen

Tags: color-management, display-calibration, icc-profile

I have an IPS LED screen and I don't like its black because it is very dark. I know it's a bit strange (is it?) but I want the black to be more bright (that means grey) without white becoming darker. A dark blue would naturally become more bright then too and so on.

The contrast setting in the LED screen is already adjusted very low, so I think an ICC Profile would be good to make it better. It shall be an ICC Profile which is active the whole time in Windows which is strictly speaking called calibration file (ICM).

I can describe my desired transformation with 4 numbers and a principle but won't insist on it exactly:

- 0 (black) to grey (0.3)
- 1 (white) to 1 (white)
- linear interpolation in between

so I think there should be a simple icc file or software to create it for my purpose? I have already digged in some icc files and saw some complicated color spaces which would be overwhelming to dig into for my purpose.

[image: transformation]

Comment: Welcome Hansebenger! In the current for, I have trouble seeing the relevance to photography. If this is simply a question on how to tweak a display to your personal taste, I am afraid, it could be deemed off-topic here. Can you give some more information on the connection to photograophy?

Comment: I searched for a stack exchange with the tags display calibration and icc profile and then photo.stackexchange came up. Can you propose an alternative stack exchange site?

Comment: Most display calibration tools let you set the black point as well as the white point to specific luminous levels like low=.25 cd/m^2 and high=100 cd/m^2 in the created ICC profile. I don't know any simple manual ways to create an ICC profile.

Comment: What do you mean with display calibration tool? Some which communicates with the screen over HDMI? Do you have an example?

Comment: Calibration tool - search 'colorimeter'… though with the caveat that you need to be spending something like $£€ 200+ before they're worth having.

Comment: I own a photospectrometer (not compatible with these tools) but I don't want a color correction to normalized colors, I want black to grey, so it is useless for this for sure. @doug I have googled a few display calibration tools, but they all need a compatible hardware device. Can you recommend a tool which doesn't need this?

Comment: I don't believe there are any tools that don't use a hardware calibration device. However, the specification for ICC profiles is public and one could certainly write code to shift black to a desired gray along with the rest of the curve. Doable but it's not a trivial task.

Comment: Yeah but since the transformation is easy, there could and should be an easy solution. I don't know yet if I will go this far otherwise (but I have already found some libraries for icc ;))

Comment: You can buy an older colorimeter for pretty cheap.  Some common ones are i1, colormunki, and spyder.  Then you can use the open-source program [DisplayCAL](https://displaycal.net/).  Their site has a list of compatible colorimeters and may have additional info to help you do what you want.

Comment: @Tetsujin Older colorimeters used to cost 200 monetary units, but now cost 20 mu.  Current colorimeters that currently cost 200 mu will someday cost 20 mu.  Why do you think they have to cost 200 mu to be worth having?  Shouldn't using an old colorimeter be better than not using one at all?

Comment: @xiota - I have three; the first two were false economy…  Huey Pro, ColorMunki (the old hockey-puck one) now i1.

Comment: @xiota Gamma lets black be black it only shifts greys.

Comment: You need a calibration tool but this isn't a photography question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have taken an ICC profile with some embedded vcgt calibration: http://fotovideotec.de/farbmanagement/downloads/testkalibrierung_blaeulich.icm.
With https://github.com/KennethEvans/colormanagement I could reverse engineer pretty quickly this particular vcgt's function and hack a desired one into it with a hex editor.

Comment: If you still find the question unapproriate on this stack exchange site, you can delete it. The appropriate stack exchange site would be in my interest.